# Pass text of Listview.ItemTemplate to antoher frame uwp

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, binding, uwp

I have to pass the `Text={Binding Id}`of textBlock idName from a frame to another frame. the text is an Id from an SQLite database. I have an Listview.ItemTemplate that define the item

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="Auto" Margin="0,5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,0,0,0">

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="idName" Text="{Binding Id}" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,12,0"/>
                                    <RelativePanel Grid.Column="1">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="titleBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="directorLabel" Text="REGISTA:" FontSize="20" RelativePanel.Below="titleBlock" FontWeight="Light"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="directorBlock" Text="{Binding Director}"  FontSize="20" RelativePanel.Below="titleBlock" RelativePanel.RightOf="directorLabel"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="yearLabel" Text="ANNO:" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" RelativePanel.RightOf="directorBlock" Margin="12,0,0,0" RelativePanel.Below="titleBlock"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="yearBlock" Text="{Binding Year}" FontSize="20" RelativePanel.Below="titleBlock" RelativePanel.RightOf="yearLabel"/>
                                    </RelativePanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I use in the Code Behind this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FilmInfo), idName.Text);
```

but `idName.Text` is an ItemTemplate.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the item must somehow be selected in the ListView in order to take action on it... if so, you can use the item directly.

```
YourClassName selectedFilm = YourListView.SelectedItem as YourClassName;
If(selectedFilm != null)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FilmInfo), selectedFilm.Id);
}
```

**UPDATE after comment**

OK... if you're using the item click event, you can do the same thing...

```
private void ItemClickEvent(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    YourClassName selectedFilm = e.ClickedItem as YourClassName;
    if(selectedFilm != null)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FilmInfo), selectedFilm.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the `ItemClick` property in XAML definition of the listview to select an item and a viewModel to interface the class. This is the code that I use to generate the listview from database: `FilmListView.ItemsSource = null;
            itemsViewModel = new FilmItemsViewModel();
            items = itemsViewModel.GetItems();
            FilmListView.ItemsSource = items;`

Comment: I've added some code that should work for your scenario.